# Django admin.py missing field error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When I include 'caption', I get an error saying **EntryAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'caption' that is missing from the form**

In the admin.py; I have imported the classes **from joe.models import Entry,Image**

Is that because my class from **models.py** is not getting imported properly ?

Need help in resolving this issue.

Thanks.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='joe')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    imageSrc = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Entry(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    mimeType = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.URLField(max_length=50)
```

**admin.py**

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
      ('File info', {'fields': ['name','password']}),
      ('Upload image', {'fields': ['image','caption']})]
    list_display = ('name', 'mimeType', 'password') 

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image)
```

Comment: Caption is a field related to `Image` and you are trying to add it against `Entry`. Try `image__caption` instead

Comment: I tried that. I did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit fields from related models directly in fieldsets.

I suspect you have your foreign key the wrong way round. If you had a FK from Image pointing to Entry, you could use inline admins:

```
class ImageInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [('File info', {'fields': ['name','password']})]
    inlines = ImageInlineAdmin
    list_display = ('name', 'mimeType', 'password') 

admin.site.register(Entry)
```